# Nodejs creating a cron task everyday at midnight and one minute

Tags: node.js, cron

I m actually developping an application where I need to use a cron task to generate some plannings at 00:01:00 with node.

I know how to do it with php, but not with node... Can you help me with this ? Which lib is the best one ?
How does it work to make it work every day at 00;01;00 ?

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) module, i have used it and it serves best for all kind of cron tasks. And the timings (according to your needs) will be like this, `new CronJob('00 01 00 * * *', function(){});` 
See it's [github](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) page for more options and it's usage.